# Usb size wrong after dd write of a ISO-Image

Tags: dd, usb-drive, fdisk, iso

I have just used `dd` to place the Kali Linux ISO file onto my USB. I then tried to install Kali Linux via the USB, but I couldn't since the install-image was corrupt. I booted back into my other Linux OS (antergos) and tried using `dd` again. My USB-Stick now says it's 32KB in size and fdisk can't detect it.

It is originally an 8GB USB 2.0 stick.

To override the MBR and Partition-table, I unsuccessfully tried:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=1`

Answer (score 3):

Your usb stick has failed.

Some drives return different sizes when they fail, although I've only read about this with regard to "SSDs", which have more complex controllers.

To double-check the size of the drive as a whole, I would use `lsblk` or look in the kernel log `dmesg`.  (The size of partitions *within* the device could be completely bogus depending on the partition table; you could contrive this without having a hardware failure).

If the size was OK, there are ways you could try to recover important data.  But it doesn't sound like you need to - you still have access to the Kali ISO file.

Simple usb sticks aren't designed with any extra hardware diagnostics[*].  Once you know the hardware has failed, that's it.  Either of the size of the drive as a whole going wrong, or the drive not returning the data you wrote to them (suggested by failure of `fdisk`), would be enough to indicate such failure.

[*] I think they're not even designed for uses where the maximum expected re-write cycles of flash storage becomes an issue.  They're much more likely to just break, or be lost.

Comment: wrong answer, my bad

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when the virtual [disk geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector) is wrongly detected. First try to reboot before proceeding.

**Warning :** I don't think this could be harmfull for your usb key but if you don't want to take any risk, please test formatting under Windows fisrt.

This guide assume you drive is `/dev/sdb`, please adapt to your need.
In a terminal, search the output of `dmesg` for such a line `sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 62545920 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)`
This tells you :

- The number of sectors (logical blocks): `62545920`
- The sectors size : `512` bytes
- The real media size : `32.0 GB/29.8 GiB`

Now calculate the exact media size in byte  : `62545920 * 512 = 32023511040 bytes = 30540 MiB` (29.82GiB).
Then find a valid CHS combination leading to `C * H * S = 62545920`
Or if you are feeling lazy, with 512 byte block size, this should work : `C=30540` (the size in MiB!), `H=64` and `S=32`

Finally, run `sudo fdisk -C 30540 -H 64 -S 32` and write a new partitaion table to fix.
Reboot if changes are not correctly detected.

Comment: Why do we have to reboot? Shouldn't have to, this isnt Windows right?

Answer (score 1):

I know this place is about `unix`, but when I have this problem I find a `windows` machine and I use `diskpart` (admin access needed). Because when `fdisk` fails, this just works; maybe it will help somebody.
I can't try the instructions right now, but it should be something like :
`list disk`, `select disk i`, `clean`, `create partition primary`, `format fs=fat32 quick`, `active`, `assign`, `exit`.
And your USB stick size is now OK (but of course, you have lost your data).
I'm also interested in an equivalent way to succeed this with linux.

NB: I'm not sure the wrong size indicates the `dd` has failed. Anyway, don't forget to append `&& sync` to your `dd` command.

Comment: `sync` is a great point. Removing the usb stick without `sync` could lose data at the end & cause the Kali boot or install to fail.  It might also cause `fdisk` error (or warning?) w.r.t. GPT partion tables, because they have a trailer at the end of the disk image as well as a header at the start like old-style MBR uses.  I can't think of an interpretation where the size 32KB would appear, but linux "ISO" hybrid images are [black magic](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/4957.html), so I am not certain about that.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a command, which if it shows `sdx` (e.g. `sda`, not `sda1`) with a size fo 32KB, would tell you the usb stick is failing and should never be trusted again :).